# Why does this code change in text editor each time on save?

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

i want to create a footer block for Follow Us

But each time i save the block i lose the code that is between span... tried different ways but no luck...

anyone know how to do this?

```
<a class="icon social-icon facebook" href="" target="_blank">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</a>
<a class="icon social-icon instagram" href="" target="_blank">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: html code and css design code....

Comment: I created block in cms > static blocks

Comment: Can you also add what it is changed to, the wysiwyg editor probably removes what are really empty html tags.

Comment: all that you see above gets lost

Comment: I got it working bij inserting &nbsp;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my understanding is that if a html element is essentially empty like these are (even though they have classes) then the tinymce witll strip out these tags. Sticking `&nbsp;` in each html node will stop this, however it will be wrapped in a `<p>` tag which may mess your code/design up a little.

To stop the `<p>` tag wrapping around the code when using `&nbsp;` we can set `settings.forced_root_block = false;` in the tiny_mce config and then to stop the need for `&nbsp;` we can add a couple of elements to the tiny_mce valid_elements setting like `settings.extended_valid_elements = '+div[*],+a[*],+span[*],+i[*]';`. With these 2 settings the tiny_mce will keep your code. *(Allthough it does put it on one line which is annoying anybody else know how to stop that?)*

But since we shouldn't just edit the core magento js file directly I would setup a small extension to add a new js file to the admin side of your site.

The important bit the js override.
js/namespace/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup-override.js note there are a couple of extra setting here that I have commented out as they are not relavant to this particular question but it may also be a good idea to leave those in probably better explained here : http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings/

```
if(window.tinyMceWysiwygSetup)
{
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.originalGetSettings = tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings;
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings = function(mode)
    {

    var settings = this.originalGetSettings(mode);
    //add any extra settings you'd like below

    //makes "placeholder" a valid element for inputs
    settings.extended_valid_elements = '+div[*],+a[*],+span[*],+i[*]';
    //settings.valid_children = 'a[h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|span|div|img]';
    //settings.force_br_newlines = true;
    //settings.force_p_newlines = false;
    settings.forced_root_block = false;
    return settings;

    }
}
```

Config.xml to add a layout.xml file

app/code/local/Namespace/Tinymce/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Tinymce>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Tinymce>
    </modules>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <namespace_tinymce>
                    <file>namespace/tinymce.xml</file>
                </namespace_tinymce>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

layout file to add the js 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/namespace/tinymce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>namespace/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/se

    tup-override.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

and ofcourse the module initalization file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Tinymce>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_Tinymce>
    </modules>
</config>
```

src : http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce

and : http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings/

Comment: nice going... i will try it out